# SoYouStart Setup Assistance

Tags: remote-desktop, hyper-v

I recently purchased an external server from a site called SoYouStart, I'm using the server to (hopefully) run Minecraft and TF2 servers. I'm having trouble getting the initial remote desktop connection set up, as I don't have physical access to the server and therefore can't physically install a program to it. The server is currently running Windows Hyper-V Server 2008 R2 as an OS (the OS is something SoYouStart assists you in installing), and my laptop is running Windows 10. Could somebody help me establish the remote desktop connection to the server so that I can start uploading the necessary files? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about you ask SoYouStart support?

Comment: They even have this nice forum where you can search for posts: https://forum.ovh.co.uk/search.php?searchid=1153517